# Running a program that's been compiled with gcc

Tags: linux, bash, executable

When I compile a C program with gcc I get the file a.exe; however, to run this I have to type in the command `./a.exe`. I believe it is possible to edit the .bashrc or .bash_profile so that I only need to write the command `a.exe`?

Comment: Putting the current directory into your `PATH` is generally considered to be a bad idea.  However, you can put your compiled program (or symbolically link it) into `~/bin/` and add _that_ to your path.

Comment: Btw, I usually get `a.out`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files ending in `.exe` are common on windows systems. On linux systems binaries usually do not have any extension.

When running `gcc` with out using `-o` to specify the name of the output file it will (for historical reasons) usually create a file named `a.out`.

When trying to run a command without specifying its location linux will search the locations in the `PATH` environment variable for the given command.

This `PATH` variable will usually intensionally *not* contain the current directory. You could add `.` (the current directory) to the list, but this would lead to unexpected effects, for example if you type `ls` you would expect to see the content of the current directory and not running some file named "ls" which might happen to live there.

Therefore if you want to run a command from a place not listed in `PATH` you need to explicitly specify its path. To run a file named `a.out` in the current directory (`.`) you have to type `./a.out`.